# Получить массив блока исходя из данных

Tags: javascript

**Привет!**

Прочитал буквально все статьи про использование map, filter, includes в JS, но все же не могу понять, как можно из полученных и пройденных проверок получить нужный мне "блок".

Задача: Есть массивы внутри объекта А, в которых есть поле 'block'. Это поле нужно сравнить с массивом Б и полученные значения сохранить, или же просто вернуть.

Первым делом я получил уникальные значения, и обьеденил их, после чего начал искать в полученном списке путём сравнения.

```
a = [
  {"id":1,"title":"123","url":"123","password":"123","totp":"none","block":"none","created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:21.000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:21.000Z"},
  {"id":2,"title":"qwe","url":"qwe","password":"qwe","totp":"none","block":"none","created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:39.000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:39.000Z"},
  {"id":3,"title":"asd","url":"asd","password":"asd","totp":"none","block":"nne","created_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:42.000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-28T20:36:42.000Z"}
  ]
 
b = ['none', '5235', '5235']


console.log(Array.from(a, ({block}) => block).map(i => i).map(al => b.map(bal => bal === al)))
```

На выходе получаем три объекта с тремя массивами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заочно я понимаю что нужные массивы сравнились, но дальше продвинуться я не могу, прошу помощи, спасибо.

P.S. Ожидаемый результат: вернуть объект с массивами, которые прошли предварительную проверку по блокам.

Comment: 1) Приведите конечный результат, который вы хотите получить на представленных в вопросе входных данных. 2) `Есть массивы внутри объекта А ... a = [{...}, ...]` По-моему тут какая-то несогласованность в обозначениях...

Comment: уже решил вопрос. достаточно отфильтровать a.filter(({block}) => b.includes(block)). Конечный результат должен быть объектом с массивами ID 1 и ID 2, т.к. там были найдены совпадения по блокам